# Имитация с помощью тире реплики-ответа. Что значит слово "Библия"? (—) Книга книг

Tags: пунктуация, диалог

**Что значит слово "Библия"? — Книга книг.**

Можно ли поставить тире после вопроса (получается как бы имитация реплики-ответа с вытекающей паузой и интонацией, и при этом всё выглядит не громоздко)? Есть ли какое-то правило на эту потребность пишущего или какие-то примеры?

Притом без тире второе предложение выглядит как обрубок или довесок. **Что значит слово "Библия"? Книга книг.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему имитация? Не обрубок и не довесок (при наличии тире, которое абсолютно обязательно разделяет реплики двух собеседников) - обычная разговорная речь, чаще всего состоящая именно из реплик.

Только одного тире маловато будет.

Если прямая речь каждого закавычена, то знаки такие:

*«Что значит слово "Библия"»? — «Книга книг».*

Если прямая речь даётся на тире, то новая реплика начинается с нового абзаца:

*— Что значит слово "Библия"?*

*— Книга книг.*

---

И правило есть - прямая речь в диалогах:

**[§ 51.2](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827535.html)**

> Если реплики следуют в подбор без указания, кому они принадлежат, то
>   каждая из них заключается в кавычки и отделяется от соседней тире:
>
> «Так ты женат? Не знал я ране! Давно ли?» — «Около двух лет». — «На
>   ком?» — «На Лариной». — «Татьяне?» — «Ты ей знаком?» — «Я им сосед»
>   (П.).
>
> ---

**[10.1.4.](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091508.html) Расположение прямой речи — диалога в кавычках, составляющего одну стихотворную строку**

> В этом случае вторую часть диалога в середине стихотворной строки либо
>   начинают с новой типографской строки, либо помещают в той же строке,
>   что и первая часть диалога. Определяет расположение автор. В любом
>   случае между частями диалога ставят тире. Например:
>
> «Стучат!» —
>
> «Эй, кто там?»

---

> «А есть у вас друзья?» — «Помилуй бог!
>
> Они меня покамест не тревожат!
>
> Ну вот, я рассказал вам все, что мог.
>
> Теперь и вы расскажете, быть может?»
>
> «Увы, исполнен горестных тревог
>
> Рассказ мой долгий! Боль мне сердце гложет!»
>
> Как видно из последнего примера, между двумя частями диалога в
>   стихотворном тексте, если предшествующая и последующая составляют
>   полную стихотворную строку, тире не ставят.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Неточно был задан вопрос, поэтому уточняю. У нас такой текст: автор пересказывает какую-ту историю из Библии и в последнем абзаце разъясняет, что такое Библия, в форме вопроса-ответа (сам задаёт и сам отвечает). Что значит "Библия"? Книга книг. И вот здесь хотелось бы выделить ответ, поставив тире. Возможно ли?

Comment: Нет, Юлия, тире будет неверным знаком. Из контекста вполне понятно, что вопрос рассказчика о Библии (ой, кстати о птицах, я прозевала: Библия никогда не кавычится!) риторический. Следующей репликой он дает ответ: "Книга книг". Никакого тире. И Книга книг (если она не оформляется как прямая речь)  тоже без кавычек, первая прописная, см. https://blaginform.ru/spravka/article/kak-pisat-nazvaniya-kanonicheskix-knig-biblii/

Comment: Спасибо! Библия никогда не кавычится? А если имеется в виду слово "Библия"? Как например: слово "аминь" значит то-то, слово "Библия" значит то-то. Что значит "Библия"? Книга книг.

Comment: Если слово, как во втором Вашем предложении, то да, кавычится. Ещё - при ироническом передразнивании. И при прямой речи: *Он раздумчиво протянул: "Библия"...* А в последнем предложении кавычки не нужны, ведь "значит" здесь в значении "означает": *Что значит Библия? Книга книг. *

Comment: Спасибо, всё понятно!